# Increment only one element in a list inside a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary whose values are a two-element-list. And I want to increment only one value of a certain key inside the dictionary. Here is what I tried:

```
my_dict = dict.fromkeys(range(0,24,2), [0,0])
my_test_key = 2
print(my_dict)
my_dict[my_test_key][0]+=1
print(my_dict)
```

This shows the following:

```
{0: [0, 0], 2: [0, 0], 4: [0, 0], 6: [0, 0], 8: [0, 0], 10: [0, 0], 12: [0, 0], 14: [0, 0], 16: [0, 0], 18: [0, 0], 20: [0, 0], 22: [0, 0]}
{0: [1, 0], 2: [1, 0], 4: [1, 0], 6: [1, 0], 8: [1, 0], 10: [1, 0], 12: [1, 0], 14: [1, 0], 16: [1, 0], 18: [1, 0], 20: [1, 0], 22: [1, 0]}
```

Which means that it adds in every "[0]" position of every key. But what I want is:

```
{0: [0, 0], 2: [1, 0], 4: [0, 0], 6: [0, 0], 8: [0, 0], 10: [0, 0], 12: [0, 0], 14: [0, 0], 16: [0, 0], 18: [0, 0], 20: [0, 0], 22: [0, 0]}
```

Pleace notice how it should be, only changing "2: [1, 0]" when it was previously "2: [0, 0]"

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: Because there is only one list in your program.  Every element in your dictionary has a reference to that one list.  You can use a list comprehension to build your dict: `my_diict = dict((i,[0,0]) for i in range(0,24,2))`.

Comment: ```>>> id(my_dict[2])
123145300839872
>>> id(my_dict[0])
123145300839872
>>>``` So you are storing reference to the same list. You change one, you change them all.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in your initialization of `my_dict`, you are storing the reference of a list in 12 places. Change any one of them, and all will point to the new value.

You can use `id()` to check if two variables points to the same thing.

```py
>>> id(my_dict[2])
123145300839872
>>> id(my_dict[0])
123145300839872
```

Here `my_dict[0]` and `my_dict[2]` are essentially the same: any change to one will reflect in another.

Here is one way to achieve what you want.

```py
>>> my_dict = { x : [0, 0] for x in range(0,24,2) }
>>> my_dict
{0: [0, 0], 2: [0, 0], 4: [0, 0], 6: [0, 0], 8: [0, 0], 10: [0, 0], 12: [0, 0], 14: [0, 0], 16: [0, 0], 18: [0, 0], 20: [0, 0], 22: [0, 0]}
>>> my_dict[2][0] += 1
>>> my_dict
{0: [0, 0], 2: [1, 0], 4: [0, 0], 6: [0, 0], 8: [0, 0], 10: [0, 0], 12: [0, 0], 14: [0, 0], 16: [0, 0], 18: [0, 0], 20: [0, 0], 22: [0, 0]}
>>>
```